# What is the advantage of conditional compilation?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

What is the advantage of using

```
#if (expression)
statement
#endif
```

instead of

```
if (expression){
statement
 }
```

?

Comment: Well, the disadvantage is twice as many builds to maintain.

Comment: the first can produce no code at all, that helps to have a code comparable only in some conditions, for instance only on windows but not on linux etc

Comment: Conditional compilation with the preprocessor directive `#if` happens at compile-time. The `if` statement is done at run-time.

Comment: Possible duplicate. Check this link
[Advantages of Conditional Compilation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17007241/advantages-of-conditional-preprocessor-over-conditional-statements)

Comment: `if (expression)` is well defined when `expression` involves FP math.  `#if (expression)` is not.