# what is the padding's role on the css and html

Tags: html, css

I sometimes use the sytle padding script

like this

```
<style>
#img1{padding:7px 10px}
</style>
<body>
<img src="myjpg.jpg" id="img1"/>
</body>
```

I can't understand exactely what the role of padding.

maybe padding's function is object's out layer margin??

Comment: This image might help.. http://i.stack.imgur.com/PeSIJ.gif ... so will this question that has already been asked on here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2189452/when-to-use-margin-vs-padding-in-css

Comment: please refer to https://www.google.com/#q=CSS+padding for your answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see in the image (shared by Josh) :

[image: padding]

Say you have an element c with parent p.

- Padding : When applied to p, adds space inside p, but outside c.
- Padding : When applied to c, adds space inside c.
- Margin : When applied to c, adds space outside c, but inside p.
- Margin : When applied to p, adds space outside p, but inside p's parent.

You may notice that 1st & 3rd case look alike when only p & c are considered.

Answer (score 0):

Padding is the distance from the outer border of an element to the inner part which contains the children.

```
+------------+
|  (Padding) |
|  +------+  |<--- Outer Border
|  |(con- |  |
|  | tent)|  |
```

Note however, that in browsers like Firefox and Chrome by default the padding gets added to the width of the element.