# box-sizing issue, margin is causing overflow

Tags: html, css, layout

Sorry for the rubbish question title, however to make up for that I have a jsFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/y167xveh/

I can't figure out why the content in the "Main Content" div is spilling out over the parents border. I've set the box-sizing mode to border-box which I thought resolved width issues like this where margins were added onto the width of the element?

```
.markBookPage div
{
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Any insight appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `margin`, use `padding` here:

```
#mbTableRootContainer {
  ...
  padding: 5px;
  ...
}
```

### Fiddle

A good description of why `margin` doesn't work is in the accepted answer at [When to use margin vs padding in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2189452/when-to-use-margin-vs-padding-in-css)

"Margins are considered to be outside of the element, and margins of adjacent items will overlap."

Comment: err, that works brilliantly, but am confused to why, I thought padding added internal space?

Comment: It's just twigged that the border is on the cells, not the container. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Well, that's a good question.  Generally, you wouldn't add a `padding` to a table element.  But in this instance, the 100% width causes the table to be the width of its parent, and the margin causes it to be offset 5px to the right.  Using `padding` instead allows the "table's" contents to be padded 5px as desired.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
#mbTableRootContainer {
    display: table;
    width: 98%;
    margin: 4px;
    height: 400px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not the css expert but your mistake is here:

```
#mbTableRootContainer {
display: table;
width: 100%;
margin: 5px;
height: 400px;
```

}

You setting your width to 100% and add a margin of 5px (left and right).

You can use the calc command:

```
width:calc(100% - 10px)
```

Comment: Unfortunately calc is ignored by IE9 if display: table is used. Thanks though, didn't know calc existed until now.

Comment: You are right. Depending on your audience this could be a problem. But check the stats here, if this is really a problem for your project:
http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc