# HTML Email columns breaking

Tags: html, email

I've build an email template that works fine in all clients, tested on Litmus. The problem is of course in 2007 Outlook. I have a two column and and three column layout that works 50% and then 50% it just breaks?

In the same email I will have one that works and then a few sections down with the exact same code it breaks?

Im using Campaign Monitor if that helps...

[image: Two column]
Two column
[image: Three Column]
Three Column

Does anyone have any idea why that would happen? I mean if it works sometimes it must be coded correctly but then why would it randomly break other times?

*edit

Here is my code, nothing seems to be fixing it in 2007 and 2010.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width"/>
        <title>Email Template</title>
        <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

        <style type="text/css">
            /*////// RESET STYLES //////*/
            body, #bodyTable, #bodyCell{height:100% !important; margin:0; padding:0; width:100% !important;}
            table{border-collapse:collapse;}
            img, a img{border:0; outline:none; text-decoration:none;}
            h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6{margin:0; padding:0;}
            p{margin:0!important;}

            /*////// CLIENT-SPECIFIC STYLES //////*/
            .ReadMsgBody{width:100%;} .ExternalClass{width:100%;} /* Force Hotmail/Outlook.com to display emails at full width. */
            .ExternalClass, .ExternalClass p, .ExternalClass span, .ExternalClass font, .ExternalClass td, .ExternalClass div{line-height:100%;} /* Force Hotmail/Outlook.com to display line heights normally. */
            table, td{mso-table-lspace:0pt; mso-table-rspace:0pt;} /* Remove spacing between tables in Outlook 2007 and up. */
            #outlook a{padding:0;} /* Force Outlook 2007 and up to provide a "view in browser" message. */
            img{-ms-interpolation-mode: bicubic;} /* Force IE to smoothly render resized images. */
            body, table, td, p, a, li, blockquote{-ms-text-size-adjust:100%; -webkit-text-size-adjust:100%;} /* Prevent Windows- and Webkit-based mobile platforms from changing declared text sizes. */

            /*////// FRAMEWORK STYLES //////*/
            .flexibleContainerCell{padding-top:30px; padding-Right:20px; padding-Left:20px;}
            .flexibleImage{height:auto;}
            .bottomShim{padding-bottom:30px;}
            .imageContent, .imageContentLast{padding-bottom:30px;}
            .nestedContainerCell{padding-top:30px; padding-Right:20px; padding-Left:20px;}

            /*////// FRAMEWORK STYLES EXTRA //////*/
            .ContainerCell{padding-top:0px; padding-Right:0px; padding-Left:0px;}
            .hero-imageContent, .heroimageContentLast{padding-bottom:0px;}

            /*////// GENERAL STYLES //////*/
            body, #bodyTable{background-color:#F5F5F5;}
            #bodyCell{padding-top:10px; padding-bottom:40px;}
            #emailBody{background-color:#FFFFFF; border:0px solid #DDDDDD; border-collapse:separate;}
            #emailHeader{background-color:#002855; border:0px solid #DDDDDD; border-collapse:separate;}
            h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6{color:#202020; font-family:'Open Sans',Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; font-size:20px; line-height:125%; text-align:Left;}
            .textContent, .textContentLast{color:#404040; font-family:'Open Sans',Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; font-size:12px; line-height:125%; text-align:Left; padding-bottom:30px;}
            .textContent a, .textContentLast a{color:#2C9AB7; text-decoration:underline;}
            .nestedContainer{background-color:#E5E5E5; border:1px solid #CCCCCC;}
            .emailButton{background-color:#2C9AB7; border-collapse:separate;}
            .buttonContent{color:#FFFFFF; font-family:'Open Sans',Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; font-size:18px; font-weight:bold; line-height:100%; padding:15px; text-align:center;}
            .buttonContent a{color:#FFFFFF; display:block; text-decoration:none;}
            .emailCalendar{background-color:#FFFFFF; border:1px solid #CCCCCC;}
            .emailCalendarMonth{background-color:#2C9AB7; color:#FFFFFF; font-family:'Open Sans',Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; font-size:16px; font-weight:bold; padding-top:10px; padding-bottom:10px; text-align:center;}
            .emailCalendarDay{color:#2C9AB7; font-family:'Open Sans',Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif; font-size:60px; font-weight:bold; line-height:100%; padding-top:30px; padding-bottom:30px; text-align:center;}

            /*////// MOBILE STYLES //////*/
            @media only screen and (max-width: 480px){          
                /*////// CLIENT-SPECIFIC STYLES //////*/
                body{width:100% !important; min-width:100% !important;} /* Force iOS Mail to render the email at full width. */

                table[id="emailBody"], table[id="emailHeader"], table[class="flexibleContainer"]{width:100% !important;}

                img[class="flexibleImage"]{height:auto !important; width:100% !important;}

                table[class="emailButton"]{width:100% !important;}
                td[class="buttonContent"]{padding:0 !important;}
                td[class="buttonContent"] a{padding:15px !important;}

                td[class="textContentLast"], td[class="imageContentLast"]{padding-top:30px !important;}

                /*////// GENERAL STYLES //////*/
                td[id="bodyCell"]{padding-top:10px !important; padding-Right:10px !important; padding-Left:10px !important;}
            }
        </style>
        <!--[if mso 12]>
            <style type="text/css">
                .flexibleContainer{display:block !important; width:100% !important;}
            </style>
        <![endif]-->
        <!--[if mso 14]>
            <style type="text/css">
                .flexibleContainer{display:block !important; width:100% !important;}
            </style>
        <![endif]-->
    </head>
    <body>
        <center>
            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" height="100%" width="100%" id="bodyTable" style="background-color;#f3f3f3:">
                <tr>
                    <td align="center" valign="top" id="bodyCell" bgcolor="#f3f3f3">
                        <!-- EMAIL CONTAINER // -->

                        <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="620" id="emailBody">

                            <repeater>

                            <layout label="Two Column">
                            <!-- MODULE ROW // -->
                            <tr>
                                <td align="center" valign="top">
                                    <!-- CENTERING TABLE // -->
                                    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                                        <tbody><tr>
                                            <td align="center" valign="top">
                                                <!-- FLEXIBLE CONTAINER // -->
                                                <table class="flexibleContainer" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600">
                                                    <tbody><tr>
                                                        <td class="flexibleContainerCell" valign="top" width="600">


                                                            <!-- CONTENT TABLE // -->
                                                            <table class="flexibleContainer" align="Left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="260">
                                                                <tbody><tr>
                                                                    <td class="imageContent" valign="top">
                                                                        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" class="flexibleImage" style="max-width:620px;" width="260" editable="true">
                                                                    </td>
                                                                </tr>
                                                                <tr>
                                                                    <td class="textContent" valign="top">
                                                                        <font face="'Open Sans', Arial, sans-serif"><multiline lable="Main Text">Erecab ium re plis nimaio quis utempos inullanis imo dent eseque pa id modipie nihitio mo offictasped quasinum re, ne occus denis nus, nosae.</multiline></font>

                                                                        <font face="'Open Sans', Arial, sans-serif"><multiline lable="Sub Text">
                                                                        Orita que poreseniae pelignimus imi, ipsus idunt et ant. Cabore omnient ommoditiur apit prorum harchic itatemporrum conet etusanda dolupist, sunt voluptae.
                                                                        </multiline></font>

                                                                        <font face="'Open Sans', Arial, sans-serif"><singleline lable="Read more"><a href="" style="color: #002855; font-size:12px; font-weight:900; text-decoration: none;">EN SAVOIR PLUS ›</a></singleline></font>
                                                                    </td>
                                                                </tr>
                                                            </tbody></table>
                                                            <!-- // CONTENT TABLE -->


                                                            <!-- CONTENT TABLE // -->
                                                            <table class="flexibleContainer" align="Right" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="260">
                                                                <tbody><tr>
                                                                    <td class="imageContentLast" valign="top">
                                                                        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" class="flexibleImage" style="max-width:620px;" width="260" editable="true">
                                                                    </td>
                                                                </tr>
                                                                <tr>
                                                                    <td class="textContent" valign="top">
                                                                        <font face="'Open Sans', Arial, sans-serif"><multiline lable="Main Text">Erecab ium re plis nimaio quis utempos inullanis imo dent eseque pa id modipie nihitio mo offictasped quasinum re, ne occus denis nus, nosae.</multiline></font>

                                                                        <font face="'Open Sans', Arial, sans-serif"><multiline lable="Sub Text">
                                                                        Orita que poreseniae pelignimus imi, ipsus idunt et ant. Cabore omnient ommoditiur apit prorum harchic itatemporrum conet etusanda dolupist, sunt voluptae.
                                                                        </multiline></font>

                                                                        <font face="'Open Sans', Arial, sans-serif"><singleline lable="Read more"><a href="" style="color: #002855; font-size:12px; font-weight:900; text-decoration: none;">EN SAVOIR PLUS ›</a></singleline></font>
                                                                    </td>
                                                                </tr>
                                                            </tbody></table>
                                                            <!-- // CONTENT TABLE -->

                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </tbody></table>
                                                <!-- // FLEXIBLE CONTAINER -->
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody></table>
                                    <!-- // CENTERING TABLE -->
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <!-- // MODULE ROW -->
                            </layout>


                            <layout label="Three Column">
                            <!-- MODULE ROW // -->
                            <tr>
                                <td align="center" valign="top">
                                    <!-- CENTERING TABLE // -->
                                    <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                                        <tbody><tr>
                                            <td align="center" valign="top">
                                                <!-- FLEXIBLE CONTAINER // -->
                                                <table class="flexibleContainer" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600">
                                                    <tbody><tr>
                                                        <td class="flexibleContainerCell" valign="top" width="600">


                                                            <!-- CONTENT TABLE // -->
                                                            <table class="flexibleContainer" align="Left" border="0" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" width="173">
                                                                <tbody><tr>
                                                                    <td class="imageContent" valign="top">
                                                                        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" class="flexibleImage" style="max-width:620px;" width="173" editable="true">
                                                                    </td>
                                                                </tr>
                                                                <tr>
                                                                    <td class="textContent" valign="top">
                                                                        <font face="'Open Sans', Arial, sans-serif"><multiline lable="Main Text">Erecab ium re plis nimaio quis utempos inullanis imo dent eseque pa id modipie nihitio mo offictasped quasinum re, ne occus denis nus, nosae.</multiline></font>

                                                                        <font face="'Open Sans', Arial, sans-serif"><multiline lable="Sub Text">
                                                                        Orita que poreseniae pelignimus imi, ipsus idunt et ant. Cabore omnient ommoditiur apit prorum harchic itatemporrum conet etusanda dolupist, sunt voluptae.
                                                                        </multiline></font>

                                                                        <font face="'Open Sans', Arial, sans-serif"><singleline lable="Read more"><a href="" style="color: #002855; font-size:12px; font-weight:900; text-decoration: none;">EN SAVOIR PLUS ›</a></singleline></font>
                                                                    </td>
                                                                </tr>
                                                            </tbody></table>
                                                            <!-- // CONTENT TABLE -->

                                                            <!-- CONTENT TABLE // -->
                                                            <table class="flexibleContainer" align="Left" border="0" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" width="173">
                                                                <tbody><tr>
                                                                    <td class="imageContent" valign="top">
                                                                        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" class="flexibleImage" style="max-width:620px;" width="173" editable="true">
                                                                    </td>
                                                                </tr>
                                                                <tr>
                                                                    <td class="textContent" valign="top">
                                                                        <font face="'Open Sans', Arial, sans-serif"><multiline lable="Main Text">Erecab ium re plis nimaio quis utempos inullanis imo dent eseque pa id modipie nihitio mo offictasped quasinum re, ne occus denis nus, nosae.</multiline></font>

                                                                        <font face="'Open Sans', Arial, sans-serif"><multiline lable="Sub Text">
                                                                        Orita que poreseniae pelignimus imi, ipsus idunt et ant. Cabore omnient ommoditiur apit prorum harchic itatemporrum conet etusanda dolupist, sunt voluptae.
                                                                        </multiline></font>

                                                                        <font face="'Open Sans', Arial, sans-serif"><singleline lable="Read more"><a href="" style="color: #002855; font-size:12px; font-weight:900; text-decoration: none;">EN SAVOIR PLUS ›</a></singleline></font>
                                                                    </td>
                                                                </tr>
                                                            </tbody></table>
                                                            <!-- // CONTENT TABLE -->

                                                            <!-- CONTENT TABLE // -->
                                                            <table class="flexibleContainer" align="Left" border="0" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" width="173">
                                                                <tbody><tr>
                                                                    <td class="imageContent" valign="top">
                                                                        <img src="http://placehold.it/350x150" class="flexibleImage" style="max-width:620px;" width="173" editable="true">
                                                                    </td>
                                                                </tr>
                                                                <tr>
                                                                    <td class="textContent" valign="top">
                                                                        <font face="'Open Sans', Arial, sans-serif"><multiline lable="Main Text">Erecab ium re plis nimaio quis utempos inullanis imo dent eseque pa id modipie nihitio mo offictasped quasinum re, ne occus denis nus, nosae.</multiline></font>

                                                                        <font face="'Open Sans', Arial, sans-serif"><multiline lable="Sub Text">
                                                                        Orita que poreseniae pelignimus imi, ipsus idunt et ant. Cabore omnient ommoditiur apit prorum harchic itatemporrum conet etusanda dolupist, sunt voluptae.
                                                                        </multiline></font>

                                                                        <font face="'Open Sans', Arial, sans-serif"><singleline lable="Read more"><a href="" style="color: #002855; font-size:12px; font-weight:900; text-decoration: none;">EN SAVOIR PLUS ›</a></singleline></font>
                                                                    </td>
                                                                </tr>
                                                            </tbody></table>
                                                            <!-- // CONTENT TABLE -->


                                                        </td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </tbody></table>
                                                <!-- // FLEXIBLE CONTAINER -->
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                    </tbody></table>
                                    <!-- // CENTERING TABLE -->
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                            <!-- // MODULE ROW -->
                            </layout>

                        </repeater>

                        </table>
                        <!-- // EMAIL CONTAINER -->
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </center>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: are you using some padding?

Comment: Yes....cellpadding="5" and I also have a class .flexibleContainerCell{padding-top:30px; padding-Right:20px; padding-Left:20px;}

Comment: try to remove those and see if they are working as expected

Comment: If I remove them there wont be any gap though?

Comment: it won't be I think you should have some dev env try that to remove to see if that is the problem than you can figure something like 49% 49% or something else

Comment: or maybe you can change padding for margin: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2189452/when-to-use-margin-vs-padding-in-css

Comment: Ok that's a good idea, I will try the margin option and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Use nested table to define padding, you can code like below:

Edited code, always use nested tables(try to avoid stack tables ), here I have showed for two column layout. Use similar way for 3 column layout.

```
<!-- FLEXIBLE CONTAINER // -->

<table class="flexibleContainer" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="600">
<tr>
<td class="flexibleContainerCell" valign="top">
<table class="flexibleContainer" align="left" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="560">
<tr>

<!-- left container // -->
<td align="left" valign="top" class="drop_col" style="padding-right:40px;">
<table class="flexibleContainer" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="260">
<tr>
left container
</tr>
</table>
</td>
<!-- end of left container // -->
<!-- right container // -->
<td align="left" valign="top" class="drop_col">
<table class="flexibleContainer" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="260">
<tr>
right container
</tr>
</table>
</td>
<!-- end of right container // -->

</tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px){  
 td[class="drop_col"]{width:100%;float:left;padding-right:0px !important;}
}
```

Comment: set cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"

Answer (score 0):

I removed all padding and replaced with margin-left and margin-right, repeated in all td elements and that seemed to work.