# Blank spaces html

Tags: html

I learnt html and css recently and there's something I don't understand how to remove the blank space on the bottom of my website : http://puu.sh/kSu7r/2fd0ed9532.png

And I have a bar http://puu.sh/kSudx/2d6c69a679.png that I would like to be fixed (stays even if I scroll down) but since the code of it involves position:relative it doesnt work ..

Here's the code:

```css
.bar {
 padding:0px;
 background-color:#333333;
 height:60px;
 top: -10px;
 width:100%;
 text-align:center;
}

.bar ul {
 position:relative;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  top: 50%;
}


.bar li {
 display:inline;
 color:white;
 font-style:Verdana;
 text-align:center;
 font-size:2em;
 font-family:'Raleway';
 margin:10px;
 padding:10px;
}

.bar a {
 text-decoration:none;
 color:white;
}
```

```html
<div class="bar">
<ul>
<li class="btn"><a href="#bottom">Element1</a></li>
<li class="btn"><a href="#bottom">Element2</a></li>
<li class="btn"><a href="#bottom">Element3</a></li>
<li class="btn"><a href="#bottom">Element4</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Thank you very much.

Comment: Can't see the blank space you are talking about from the png links.  As far as keeping the menu bar fixed, just use position: fixed.

Answer (score 1):

So first I started with: `.bar` in CSS. Couple of things I'll change.

For the `.bar` class I would remove the `padding:0;`, `height:40px`, `top:-10px;`. You remove `padding` because `div` tags have no padding already, `height` will be controlled by the `ul` (more on that later). And I believe you were using `top` to get rid of the whitespace, but we fix that later.

Next we go to `ul`tag. Remove `position:relative;`, `transform:translateY(-50%);`, and `top:50%;`. Then add `margin:0;`, and `padding:20px 0`. I could tell that you were trying to use `position` to center the `ul` within your `.bar` div. We handle that with the `padding` addition. I remove the `margin` because the `ul` tag has built in margins and you want to remove that or you will have whitespace.

Final touch is the `li` tag. I just change `display: inline;` to `display: inline-block` allowing the `ul` padding to work.

This is only for the code you added to your post, don't understand the other issues you linked about, might need code for those. Hope this helped!

EDITED

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-family: 'Helvetica';
    background-color: #E6E6E6;
}


.bar {
    background-color:#333333;
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
}

.bar ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 20px 0;
}


.bar li {
    display:inline-block;
    color:white;
    font-style:Verdana;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:2em;
    font-family:'Raleway';
    margin:10px;
    padding:10px;
}

.bar a {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:white;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer ! Problem is that when I deleted position:relative;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
  top: 50%;
The li elements aren't showing up in the middle of the bar anymore : http://puu.sh/kSAFm/ffbb7ce08d.png

Comment: Did you add `margin:0;` and `padding:20px 0` and did you change `li`'s `display:inline;` to `display:inline-block;`?

Comment: @Zenoxis I just updated my answer with what your css should look like now.

Comment: Okay it worked, thanks ! Could you please explain me when to use padding and margin ? I'm a bit confused :s

Comment: I had to reduce .bar ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 20px 0;
}
to
.bar ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0px 0;
}
btw because otherwise the bar was too huge, is that normal?

Comment: I tend to use padding to give spacing around the content, and margin to separate content from other content. Here's a question that was asked here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2189452/when-to-use-margin-vs-padding-in-css

Comment: @Zenoxis I use padding to set the height instead of setting an actual height, mainly to make it responsive. I would actually remove the padding on the `li` tag. And change it's margin to `margin:0 10px` (This will remove the height added by the margin).