# Remove last margin for text in bootstrap input-addon

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I´m trying to remove the last margin, for the text, on the "input-addon" for Bootstrap.

I´ve borrowed a fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/Dzhz4/250/

**HTML**

```
<div class="input-group">
  <div class="input-group-addon">Lit:</div>
    <input type="text" style="width: 40px" class="form-control input-sm"/>';
</div>';
```

**CSS**

```
.input-group-addon {
  max-width:30px;
  text-align:left !important;
}
```

**EDIT**
I´ve learned, i need padding. Not Margin.

Comment: Last margin means will you please describe little more for better understanding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is `padding` not `margin`.

```
.input-group-addon {
  min-width: 300px;
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 0;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Dzhz4/252/

Using something like Chrome Dev Tools is invaluable for finding stuff like this. I recommend learning how to use the element inspector as a starting point.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you! I need to reed up on margin and padding!

Comment: Here's a great SO answer to help you there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2189452/when-to-use-margin-vs-padding-in-css. Please remember to mark as Answer if it helped you. Cheers!