# Bootstrap - empty lines between content

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to add empty spaces between text content in correct way (without using nbsp) to look like on image, how can I do that?

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/siuq6.jpg)

**Index.html**

```
    <div class="container-fluid" id="home">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-5"></div>
        <div class="col-md-7">
               <h1>Text A</h1>
               <h1>Text B</h1>
               <h1>&nbsp;</h1><h1>&nbsp;</h1><h1>&nbsp;</h1><h1>&nbsp;</h1>
               <h1>Text after space</h1>
               <h1>&nbsp;</h1>
               <h1>&nbsp;</h1>
               <h1>Example</h1>
               <h1>Second examplei</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    <div class="col-md-4"></div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
h1{
margin: 0px;
padding: 1px 0;
line-height:1;
font-size: 28px;}
```

Comment: Please look at the css property `margin` and play with it :) also suggest to read [margin vs padding](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2189452/when-to-use-margin-vs-padding-in-css) to know the difference. Take the time to learn, goodluck!

Answer (score 4):

You could solve it with some simple css padding

Working [Codepen Example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GZJZOd)

```
 .spacer {
     padding-top: 80px;
     padding-bottom: 40px
 }
```

Cheers :)

Answer (score 2):

```
.space { margin:0; padding:0; height:50px; } // height as desired

<div class="space"></div>
```

You can replace this code instead of `<h1>&nbsp;</h1>`

Answer (score 1):

Please use `padding` css property. `Padding-top:"";` `padding-bottom:"";` would be fine.