# Problems with adding margin

Tags: html, css, margin

Link to the website: https://jsfiddle.net/L84vhah9/

Now go into the CSS, go all the way down to `.box` and change the `margin: 0 auto;` to `margin: 2% auto;`

Then check the website again. See how the whole `section` moves/gets the margin instead of just the `box`. It creates a space between the `nav` and `section`.

Why is this happening?

Shouldn't just the `.box` get the margin? I don't understand why `<section>` gets it.

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding what `margin` does. If you imagine your box element, margin will give it space outside of its border, and padding will give it space inside its border. 

There are some more well-put explanations here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2189452/when-to-use-margin-vs-padding-in-css

Comment: @Lucas

I understand what margin and padding does.
You might've missunderstood my problem.
I want to add space on the top and bottom sides of the box, but when I did that it behaved like the section got the margin which created a space between the nav and the section with the section being the white space that the green boxes were inside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/L84vhah9/7/)

You could easily solve the problem by adding

```
overflow:auto;
```

or

```
overflow: hidden;
```

to the parent div..ie to your `section`.

Thus, the updated CSS for `section` and `.box` would be as follows

```
section {
    overflow: hidden;
  width: 90%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.box {
  width: 90%;
  height: 300px;
  margin: 2% auto;
  border: 5px solid #36FF54;
  background: #ffffff;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!
This was the only thing needed.
Could you explain why it was behaving like it did before without overflow?

Comment: Great.. :) Glad that it helped you.. Actually, earlier I too had the same problem and while searching stack overflow I heard somebody saying that it is because the parent div fails to consider the height of the child div for some reason and hence that behaviour..

Comment: Okay, makes a bit more sense now but I am still kinda lost.
Thanks a lot anyway! Finally fixed it. :)

Comment: Happy to help.. :)... @Fotan could you please mark the answer as accepted if it really helped you..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1762539/margin-on-child-element-moves-parent-element

Comment: @Lal

Ok, No worries! :D

Comment: Better to use a proper `.clearfix` than `overflow:hidden` or **better/rather** `overflow:auto`.

Comment: understood @RokoC.Buljan..Thankyou for that info..