# 100% width extends past parent element

Tags: html, css, width

I'm using HTML and CSS to code a card-like button.

For some reason, the `width` of the text under the image always extends past the edge of the parent `div`.

I can adjust to make it relatively unnoticeable when viewing on desktop, but it becomes a real pain when it comes to viewing on mobile devices.

```css
.card {
  width: 20%;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px gray;
}
.card:hover {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px black;
}
.card-img {
  width: 100%;
}
.card-title {
  margin: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: Open Sans;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <img class="card-img" src="http://prww-weather.com/logo.png" />
  <p class="card-title">Card Title</p>
</div>
```

Does anyone know why `card-title` extends past the edge of `card` and how I can fix it?

I think it has something to do with the `inline-block` assigned to the `card-title` class, but if I don't include that, the `margin`s of `card-title` and `card-img` collapse .

Comment: Most of the CSS frameworks have box-sizing set to `border-box` by default.  Because this gives more control when your layouts are fluid and works with percentages.  If you are starting a new project,  I would recommend to set the box model as the first setting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this:

https://jsfiddle.net/nbLLgx5x/

```css
.card {
    width: 20%;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px gray;
}

.card:hover {
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px black;
}

.card-img {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}

.card-title {
    padding: 10px;
    font-family: Open Sans;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
    <img class="card-img" src="http://prww-weather.com/logo.png" />
    <p class="card-title">This is a very long card title</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I like your answer because I don't have to mess with `box-sizing`

Answer (score 2):

It is all due to margin:10px that you have assigned for card-title. That will consume 100% of the **parent width + 10px on left and 10px on the right**

To have a gutter space around the card-title and constrain it within parent bounds, use `padding:10px` for card-title, 
and enable  `box-sizing: border-box;` property on all elements. (border-box will allow the padding, borders to be considered as part of element width itself)

```css
* {
   box-sizing: border-box;
}
.card {
  width: 20%;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px gray;
}
.card:hover {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px black;
}
.card-img {
  width: 100%;
}
.card-title {
  padding: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: Open Sans;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <img class="card-img" src="http://prww-weather.com/logo.png" />
  <p class="card-title">Card Title</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `padding` and `border-box`

```css
 .card {
  width: 20%;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px gray;
}
.card:hover {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px black;
}
.card-img {
  width: 100%;
}
.card-title {
margin: 0;
  padding: 10px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: Open Sans;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <img class="card-img" src="http://prww-weather.com/logo.png" />
  <p class="card-title">Card Title</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

That's because you have `margin` applied when you should be using `padding`

(`margin`s are for outer space, `padding`s are for inner space, so as your `.card-title` is a child and you want some space around it but no more than the parent, `padding` to the rescue).

But because you are now using `padding` you need `box-sizing` to get the `width` calculated right regarding `box-model`.

Also you might want to set `display:block` in your `img` to remove a gap.

A great article about [**box-sizing**](https://css-tricks.com/box-sizing/)

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box
}
.card {
  width: 20%;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px gray;
}
.card:hover {
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px black;
}
.card-img {
  width: 100%;
  display:block
}
.card-title {
  padding:5px  10px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-family: Open Sans;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  margin:0;
  border:1px solid red
}
```

```html
<div class="card">
  <img class="card-img" src="http://prww-weather.com/logo.png" />
  <p class="card-title">Card Title</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem here is the combination of `width: 100%;` and `margin: 10px;`

To put it simply you card-title will take the width of your card and there will also be **an additional width from your margin** ( here 2*10 = 20px ) and that will finally be wider than your parent element (card) therefore your text will be centered in the card-title but the card-title itself will be moved to the right by 10px here.

So here you should use padding instead of margin. Quick reminder about how those 2 works ( Credit to [John Boker's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2189452/when-to-use-margin-vs-padding-in-css) ):

Margin is on the outside of block elements while padding is on the inside.

- Use margin to separate the block from things outside it
- Use padding
  to move the contents away from the edges of the block.

[image]

Here is an images that explains it well from https://www.impressivewebs.com/width-100-percent-css/ :
[image]