# How to color footer margins?

Tags: html

Well , I have a site with margins and a footer with different background color.
The problem is that the footer margins do not get colored in the same color as the specified footer color.
The Html code -

Here I would like color the green space orange.
I have tried replacing the margin with padding , but it does not work .

**Now the problem has been resolved. Do not answer.**

Comment: Please provide code for it.

Comment: It is much better to place your code here for the community to review it rather than link to it elsewhere. Please paste the relevant parts here.

Comment: Not only better-- safer-- I am _always_ hesitant to blindly click a link to some unknown site (or somebody's Google Drive) as opposed to known code hosting sites.

Comment: you could place a wrapper `<div>` around the footer and give it the desired background color.

Answer (score 0):

Use`padding` css property on footer instead of `margin`.

Margin, as such, doesn't have background color. Margin is invisible border, a space between two objects.

Refer this [Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2189452/when-to-use-margin-vs-padding-in-css) to understand more.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell without seeing the code but I'm assuming that if changing the margin to padding for your footer div didn't work then that element might be nested inside of the element with the margin that you're saying you're applying for the site.  Move the footer DIV outside of that element and apply the padding to it, not sure though without seeing the code so I could be off on that

Answer (score 0):

You should use padding instead of margin in such case..