# Spacing rows evenly inside div

Tags: html, css

I have a div that has a table inside it, and it uses  to create the links to it. So far, that's all I have done for the website. I'm attempting to space out the rows so that I can implement jQuery into it, however, I haven't started that yet.

My problem is that I can't get the rows to space evenly throughout the div. I've tried padding-left/right, however, that doesn't work with width and height, and margin-left/right aren't working. Is there a way to do this? Or, should I just get rid of the idea of using a table and create divs for each nav option?

[Code](https://repl.it/Hj62/2)

Comment: Can you please provide an example with >1 row?

Comment: @UghThatGuyAgain - It's not clear for me what are you trying to achieve - if you make the table 100% width the rows will "space evenly  throughout the div". In general using tables for positioning elements is not a good idea.

Comment: @Picard I should've been more specific, I want them evenly spaced throughout the div, while providing even space between the rows. I'll attempt to recreate the same thing using divs, I found this easier to do though. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one possible solution using lists and display:flex for positioning. Your updated example: https://repl.it/Hj62/6.

HTML part:

```
<div id="header-nav-content">
  <ul class="table-nav-content">
     <li class="nav-home">Home</li>
     <li class="nav-about">About</li>
     <li class="nav-contact">Contact</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

CSS part:

```
.table-nav-content {
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-around;
    padding: 0;
}
.table-nav-content li {
    list-style: none;
}
```

You can also check if:

```
justify-content: space-between;
```

doesn't suit you better. You can find more about flex positioning, for example: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Thank you! This answer worked the best for me, I just removed the extra home2/3 and so on, and I'll readjust the size of them to make sure they'll look good.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you use the HTML list approach, https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_lists.asp. You might want to use margin not padding to space out each item evenly, [When to use margin vs padding in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2189452/when-to-use-margin-vs-padding-in-css).

```
<ul style="list-style:none;">
        <li style="display:block;float:left;margin:5px" class="nav-home">Home</li>
        <li style="display:block;float:left;margin:5px" class="nav-about">About</li>
        <li style="display:block;float:left;margin:5px" class="nav-contact">Contact</li>
</ul>
```