# In css when to use padding and when to use margin

Tags: html, css

With reference to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2189452/when-to-use-margin-vs-padding-in-css), if I want to align a `div` to left by `20px`, I can use both `padding-left` or `margin-left`. Which one is preferred and in which case?

```
<div style="padding-left: 20px;">
    Move me by 20px left!
</div>

<div style="margin-left: 20px;">
    Move me by 20px left!
</div>
```

Comment: Apply `background-color:red;` to both. See what happens. Decide for yourself.

Comment: nice pointer thanks.

Comment: it all comes clear when the background or border element is styled and when among other contents. margin is to put space between elements, padding is mostly used to push contents away from edges for visual clarity

Comment: Padding is space inside an element. Margin is space outside an element.

Comment: Refer to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Styling_boxes/Box_model_recap

Comment: Your question title typed into Google verbatim yields a popular duplicate, plus lots of other results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This image can help you understand better.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

To build off of what @G-Cyr said, think of it in terms of pictures on a wall.

Your picture is your element in question; the frame around the picture can be considered the padding, or the immediate space surrounding image, yet unique to that element. Margin could be considered the spacing between two of the pictures on said wall.

From a philosophical standpoint, you may want to defer to margin when changing spacing between two elements.

Comment: I think picture from @Nick's response helps to illustrate this.

Answer (score 0):

The fact is that **margin** is used to add space to things from the outside while **padding** is used to add spacing inside of that same thing, but for your question i am not sure if you're talking about aligning group of **div** as an example to the left, if i am to do that i will use the keyword alight-left which is available in css.