# Using Padding instead of Margins to space Siblings

Tags: css, margin, padding, spacing

The pink block li elements in my code are spaced out because I used margins, but I've that it better to use padding in this case, except every time I try to replace the margin properties with padding, I cannot separate the pink blocks from each other.
How do I use padding instead of margins to space out the li elements?

I tried googling stuff about this, but all that comes up are more practical applications of CSS like styling a website and spacing text, and I can't figure out how it applies to my work.

[This is what it should look like (which I made using margin properties)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kv1D2.png)

```css
    .blue-container {
      background-color: #141f40;
      height: 100px;
      width: 400px;
      position: relative;
    }
    .white-container {
      background-color: #fff;
      height: 60px;
      width: 160px;
      position: absolute;
      top: 20px;
      left:220px;
    }
    .white-container > li{
      background-color: #a9004b;
      height: 40px;
      width: 40px;
      float: left;
      margin-top: 10px;
      margin-left: 10px;
    }
```

```html
    <!DOCtype HTML>
        <html lang="jp">
        <head>
          <title>Siblings</title>
          <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
          <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/3.18.1/build/cssreset/cssreset-min.css">
        </head>
        <body>
          <main>
            <div class="blue-container">
              <ul class="white-container">
                <li>1</li>
                <li>2</li>
                <li>3</li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </main>
        </body>
        </html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When to use margin vs padding in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2189452/when-to-use-margin-vs-padding-in-css)

Comment: I kind of just threw in the second question last minute without searching the site for it. I shouldn't have done that. I deleted that question. But even after reading that answer I still could not figure out how to make the li elements space out, the parent would just get bigger in size when I applied padding.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you need to understand is the relationship between **[`margin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/margin)** and **[`padding`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/padding)**. Margins are used to 'offset' an element from its **parent**. Padding, conversely, is used to denote how much space there should be between the edge of an element and its **children**.

This is demonstrated in the **[box model](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Introduction_to_CSS/Box_model)**:

[image: Box Model]

According to your desired image, your first step would be to ensure that the `.white-container` is actually contained within the `.blue-container`. This can be done by simply adjusting the **[`top`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/top)** and **[`left`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/left)**. From here it's just a matter of applying the `padding` to the **parent** (`.white-container`).

You'll probably also want to hide the bullet points in the **[`<li>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/li)** elements, which can be done with **[`list-style: none`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/list-style)**, as seen in the following:

```css
.blue-container {
  background-color: #141f40;
  height: 100px;
  width: 400px;
  position: relative;
}

.white-container {
  background-color: #fff;
  height: 60px;
  width: 160px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 220px;
  padding: 5px;
}

.white-container>li {
  background-color: #a9004b;
  height: 40px;
  width: 40px;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCtype HTML>
<html lang="jp">

<head>
  <title>Siblings</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/3.18.1/build/cssreset/cssreset-min.css">
</head>

<body>
  <main>
    <div class="blue-container">
      <ul class="white-container">
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>3</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </main>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

**margins** create/define a *distance* to the neighboring elements, *outside of the border* of the element. Therefore they won't be filled by the background image or background color, since that is always restricted to the area within the border.

**paddings** are *inside the border* and create some space/distance between the border and the element's contents (so for example text content doesn't touch the borders, but keeps some distance to the borders). Since they are inside the border, they *are* filled by the background image or background color.

In your case, you clearly need margins therefore.

Comment: Right, that's what I thought! But I was told to recreate this with padding instead. And apparently it is possible...?

Comment: The only possible way to do that with padding would be to apply padding to the white container and distribute the three purple squares over the whole width by using `display: flex` and `justify-contents: space-between` on the white container. But the space between the three purple squares wouldn't really be padding in that case, so doing it strictly with padding is actually impossible.