# Why does the gap between to divs get bigger when screen gets smaller and how do I prevent it?

Tags: html, css

It seems like the more narrow the width gets the more everything gets further apart. How can I prevent this from happening?

[image]

```css
.section1 {
  background: url("img/Rectangle 1.jpg") no-repeat center;
  background-size: 100% auto;
  padding: 300px 0;
}

.section2 {
  background: url("img/Diagnostic.jpg") no-repeat center;
  background-size: 100% auto;
  padding: 500px 0;
}
```

```html
<section class="section1">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12 info" align="center">
        Make Future Visible <span>&trade;</span>
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12 info2" align="center">
        Real-time predictive analytics for refining equipment eliminate accidents<br> and fires, increases refinery uptime, decreases downtime and drastically<br> reduces maintenance costs.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>


<section class="section2">

</section>
```

Comment: Can you insert your HTML code?

Answer (score 0):

That is because your `padding` settings. When you set `padding: 300px 0;` it translates to:

```
padding-top: 300px;
padding-right: 0;
padding-bottom: 300px;
padding-left: 0;
```

When you resize the gap between `.section1` and `.section2` will be 800px (300px + 500px), `padding` do not auto-collapse. Try to use `margin` instead.

See [When to use margin vs padding in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2189452/when-to-use-margin-vs-padding-in-css)

Or you can set a `min-height`

Comment: but if I don't set a padding my photos won't even show up

Comment: Set a `min-height` then

Comment: Go for media query and change the padding accordingly and also use margin instead of padding

Comment: Try giving padding in em instead of px. That's more mobile friendly