# I'd like to apply margin-top inside the box

Tags: css

Apply this code and you can see it. The margine-top of the internal box is applied to the outside. How can inBox not affect the box?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>
.box{
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: red;
}
.inBox{
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: white;

  margin-top: 100px;
}
  </style>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
  <div class = "box">
    <div class = "inBox">
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That's how `margin` works; `margin` pushes the target element away from its *parent*. Are you sure you're not looking for `padding`, which pushes the target element's *content* away from *the element*?

Comment: [When to use margin vs padding in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2189452/when-to-use-margin-vs-padding-in-css)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you actually can have `margin-top` on the child element. As mentioned by others, vertical margins can collapse. This is one of the least intuitive instances, where the `margin-top` of the child is apparently going right through the parent.

You can counter this by adding any amount of padding to the parent. I added 1px of `padding-top` and the margin suddenly appears to behave as originally expected:

```css
.box {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  background-color: red;
  padding-top: 1px;
}

.inBox {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: white;
  margin-top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="inBox">.inBox has margin-top</div>
</div>
```

As recommended by others I would also probably just use `padding-top` on the parent to create all of the space but this trick exposes an interesting nuance of margin collapse.

Answer (score 0):

You can’t do margins inside an element. You can use padding. If you don’t want the padding to affect the side of the box, also set `box-sizing: border-box`.

Vertical margins have some unintuitive characteristics, like collapsing. There are ways to prevent [vertical margin collapse](https://css-tricks.com/what-you-should-know-about-collapsing-margins/) that may solve your issue.